# after build jar, popup the error NoSuchMethodError for int but long ok

Tags: java

I have one class:

```
public RetryAfterEntity(boolean retryAfter, long retryAfterTime, int returnStatusCode) {}
```

and I call the constructor  with this methods:

```
  private RetryAfterEntity retryAfterEntity=new RetryAfterEntity(false, 20, 405);
```

it isn't report any compile error.

but when I use mvn deploy to build the code to jar, and run it, it will popup error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sip.core.telephone.header.entity.RetryAfterEntity.<init>(ZII)V
```

after update the **20** to **20l**, it is all ok? so what's the root cause?

Comment: I cannot reproduce such behaviour - no errors with simple example, can you provide full example that produces error.

Comment: Strange, I can not reproduce it either ... How are you running the jar file ?

Comment: Are you using "-source 1.4 " command line option when running this?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
private RetryAfterEntity retryAfterEntity=new RetryAfterEntity(false, 20L, 405);
```

The reason is the compiler automatically reads integers as.. int. You need to tell him that this 20 isn't an int by using "L".

Same scenario applies to doubles and floats - you have to write

```
float x = 3.15f;
```

because compiler automatically reads non-integer numbers as double.